# Move files to sub folders based upon year and month LastWriteTime persevering subfolder

Tags: powershell

Could you help me with a modification to this script?

I have a root folder with several sub folders

c://root/ many-subfolders/ many-logfiles.

I would like the sctipt to sort long files year /month and output to the original subfolder excluding files from current year

c://root/many-subfolders/year/month/logfiles

```
$Filepath  = ""
$file      = ""
$date      = ""
$month     = ""
$year      = ""
$MonthPath = ""

$FilePath = Read-Host "Place the directory which contains the files."

Write-Warning "Note: This action can take several minutes, depending on the amount of files in $FilePath."

Get-ChildItem $FilePath | % {
    $file = $_.FullName 
    $date = Get-Date ($_.LastWriteTime)

    $month = $date.Month
    $year = $date.Year
    $MonthPath = "$FilePath\$year\$month"
    Write-Verbose "month = $month"
    Write-Verbose "Date = $date"
    Write-Verbose "year = $year"
    Write-Verbose "FilePath = $FilePath" 
    Write-Verbose "Filename = $file"
    Write-Verbose "MonthPath = $MonthPath"

    if (!(Test-Path -Path "$MonthPath" )) {
        Write-Verbose "Creating log location $MonthPath."
        #Write-Host -BackgroundColor green -ForegroundColor black "Creating log location $MonthPath."
        Write-Verbose "MonthPath inside path test = $MonthPath"
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $MonthPath | Out-Null
    } else {
        #Write-Host -BackgroundColor green -ForegroundColor black "Log location exists already exist $MonthPath"
        Write-Verbose "Log location exists already exist $MonthPath" 
    }
    Move-Item "$file" "$MonthPath" | Out-Null
}

Write-Warning "All files are sorted now based upon year and month."
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to make this work yourself? What didn't work the way you expected? SO is not a free script (re-)writing service.

Comment: what I need is to replicate the sub dir structure of the unsorted files in the files sorted by year/month,   for example you have c:// rootfolder/ many subfolders / years of log files .   the script in its current state does not sort files in relation to the  sub folder it comes from it just puts all together.  also i need to ignore the log files of this current year .  just want to sort these millions of log files

Comment: also im new to powershell

Comment: It's OK to be new to a language, but SO is not a replacement for familiarizing yourself with a new language. If you're so new that you cannot even try anything yet you need to find a tutorial first and get accustomed to the basic concepts.

Comment: i was hoping on learning from example can you help me sir? :)

Answer (score 1):

as I can understand you need to filter all your files in the c:\root\ and then move them to a new directory.

```
    # Set the $Filepath you are going to search for the files, if you have a specific extension you may filter that for better results and performance.
    $FilePath = "C:\setup\testlogs"

        # Put all the files to an variable with some of their attributes you may need the CreationTime or the LastWriteTime depends on what you need!!!!
        $AllFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Setup\TestLogs -File -Recurse |select Name, FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime

        Foreach ($File in $AllFiles) 
            {
            # Put an if with less than the date you want the logs to be moved.
            If ($File.LastWriteTime -lt "11/07/2018")
                {
                    Write-Host "The file is ready for archive"
                    $Date = Get-Date ($File.LastWriteTime) -Format dd/MM/yyyy
                    $Month = $File.LastWriteTime.Month
                    $Year = $File.LastWriteTime.Year
                    $NewPath = "$FilePath\$year\$month"
                    $CheckExist = Test-Path $FilePath\$year\$month
                    # Check if the path already exist and move the file to the folder Else create the new folder and move the file there
                    If ($CheckExist -eq $true)
                        {
                        Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $FilePath\$year\$month\
                        }
                    Else
                        {
                        New-Item -Path $Filepath\$year\$month -ItemType Directory
                        Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $FilePath\$year\$month\
                        }
                }
            Else 
                {
                    Write-Host "The File is not that old to be archived"
                }
            }
```

I hope this is what you are looking for!

Let me know so I can help you more with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me StefTheo just testing

Comment: hi StefTheo, i get an error when running this script. was your input ment to run as is?

Comment: You must change your input, in the $Filepath you must put your path.
the C:\setup\testlogs is a test path I used to put some files so I can sort them by month and year.
Then in the If you must set your own -lt (less than) date as you are say that you don't want to move the current years logs.
I believe that changing those things will get your script running.
If you are getting an error please post the error you are getting.